# WatchKit: modal controller with it's own hierarchical navigation

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2, wkinterfacecontroller

Watchkit offers 3 types of navigation: Page-based, modal and hierarchical interfaces.

Imagine that kind of hierarchy:

Main controller V1 -> Modal controller V2 -> Push to controller V3

The main issue I'm facing: how to push V3 controller from the modal interface controller V2, is it possible?